# How to transfer 2-D array into a 1-D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2-D numpy array `arr`:

```
array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]]
```

I want to convert it to a 1-D vector:

```
vec = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
```

The values 0, 1 and 2 should correspond to a column of `art`, in which the value is equal to 1.

Is there any non-for loop way to do it?

Comment: `np.nonzero(your_array)[1]`

Comment: `np.argmax(arr, 1)`.  This assumes that there is a single `1` per row (otherwise the first will be chosen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [numpy.**nonzero**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[0., 1., 0.],
...               [1., 0., 0.],
...               [1., 0., 0.],
...               [0., 0., 1.],
...               [1., 0., 0.],
...               [1., 0., 0.]])
>>> np.nonzero(a)[1]
array([1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0])
```

or [numpy.**where**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> np.where(a)[1]
array([1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use matrix math to solve this because you have only one non-zero value per row. A simple dot-product with a "position" vector will give you the desired output. You want to emulate the matrix equation A*x = y, and so long as x is a column vector, you will end up with a column vector as the answer.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[0., 1., 0.],
...               [1., 0., 0.],
...               [1., 0., 0.],
...               [0., 0., 1.],
...               [1., 0., 0.],
...               [1., 0., 0.]])
>>> x = (0,1,2)
>>> y = np.dot(a,x)
>>> y
array([1., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0.])
```

Using this method, you can change your "position" vector to be whatever you want and it will "index" appropriately (I put that in quotes since it is a math trick). For example:

```
>>> x = (2,4,8)
>>> np.dot(a,x)
array([4., 2., 2., 8., 2., 2.])
```

Comment: To generalize this a bit, you could use `a.dot(np.arange(a.shape[1]))`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a.nonzero()[1]
array([1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

For more flexible conditions

```
>>> np.nonzero(a==1)[1]
array([1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], dtype=int64)

>>> np.where(a==1)[1]
array([1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], dtype=int64)

>>> np.where(a>0)[1]
array([1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```